# EXM custom email template not showing up

Tags: exm

I followed this article to create a custom email template: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--building-a-custom-message-template.html

However, it's not showing up in the EXM dialog. 
Any suggestions/insights? 
`Sitecore version 9.2`, 
`EXM version 3.5.1 rev. 171103`

[image]

Comment: Have you performed this action: In the Insert Options dialog, navigate to your message template, for example, /templates/Branches/System/Email/Messages/Custom Newsletter/Monthly Newsletter and add it to the Selected pane.

Comment: In this path: "/sitecore/templates/Branches/System/Email/Manager Root", for the message types I have added the newly created template to the insert options. Still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you add the custom template to this item's `Insert Option` ? `/sitecore/content/*EXM Email Manager Root*/Message Types/Regular/Default`

**/sitecore/content/EXM Email Manager Root/Message Types/Regular/Default**
[image: Insert Option]

Publish the item. Then it should appear in the `EXM Regular Template Option`

**EXM Regular Template Option**
[image: EXM Regular email campaign]

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion!!

Answer (score 0):

Since we have multi site implementation, I had to go to each site's Email Manager Root and assign the template to the insert options. i.e. here in .../Emails/Message Types/Automated/Default I added the newly created email template to the insert option for Default and it worked!!

[image]

Thanks to all who helped from the slack.